# how do I do an azcli task with an spn?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Ive got a devops pipeline and im trying to use the azcli task to look at blobs but I dont thin k its logging in successfully, im trying to log in with a service principal but I dont think its working. Any ideas whats wrong?

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubScription:'$(subName)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az login --service-principal -u $servicePrincipalId -p $servicePrincipalKey --tenant $tenantId
      if [ $? -eq 0]; then
        echo 'Azure login success'
      else
        echo 'Azure login failure'
        exit $?
      fi
      az storage blob list --account-name $(accountName) --container-name $(containerName)
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
```

I know that the cli task should login automatically I added the login and the if as a way of checking what was going on and it now saysazure login failure all the time which explains why I keep on getting no results from the storage blob list in the logs.
Above the login failed output in the logs it says "/home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitasksript1704664334724.sh: line 2: [:missing `]'
Any idea what this means?

Comment: It's telling you there's a syntax error in your Bash script. If you want help, you really need to include the *exact* error message, not your synopsis of what the error said. If you're using the `AzureCLI@2` task, you don't need to call `az login` directly in your script; the task handles authenticating for you with the provided service connection.

Comment: if you use AzureCLI@2 task, the task itself do the login for you, you don't need to get additional command to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message,

> ***line 2: [:missing `]'***

The line 2 (**`if [ $? -eq 0]; then`**) in your bash script has a syntax error. you need to correct this line by add a whitespace after the condition like as below:

```bash
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

---

When using **`if`** statement in bash script, the correct syntax should look like below.

```bash
if [ condition ]
```

You need to ensure the whitespaces exist before and after the **`condition`** between the brackets (**`[ ]`**). If you miss any of the whitespaces between the brackets, bash will report an error about a "**`missing ]`**" just like as the one you get.

For example, the following will not work and report the error:

```bash
if [$x==0]

if [ $x==0]

if [$x==0 ]
```

---

Comment: thank you Ive never used bash before and assumed I was missing brackets somewhere and would never have guessed whitespace was an issue